# Refactor to show link or not in blade

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I felt this code look a bit messy, the logic is to show a link `<a href` or otherwise show text only.

How can I refactor this to look cleaner and maintainable?

```
   <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li class="{{ $active == 'sign_in'? 'active':'' }}">
            @if($active != 'sign_in')
                @php($showLink = true)
            @else
                @php($showLink = false)
            @endif

            @if($showLink)
                 <a href="{{ url_secure('sign_in') }}">
            @endif
                Sign In
            @if($showLink)
                </a>
            @endif
        </li>
        <li class="{{ $active == 'article'? 'active':'' }}"> 
            @if($active != 'article' && $showLink)
                @php($showLink= true)
            @else
                @php($showLink= false)
            @endif

            @if($showLink)
                 <a href="{{ url_secure('article')}}">
            @endif
                Articles
            @if($showLink)</a>@endif
        </li>

        <li> </li> //repeat the code logic like above
     </ol>
```

It would be good if there a way to reduce if conditions and use loop.

Comment: What do you mean with `//repeat the code logic like above` as in how exactly will it be repeated?

Comment: @RossWilson Like on second `<li>` block but with different url, text and different value of `$active`

Comment: Are you asking about loops?

Comment: @Script47 Yep and reduce if condition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just:

```
<li class="{{ $active == 'sign_in'? 'active':'' }}">
    @if ($active != 'sign_in')
        <a href="{{ url_secure('sign_in') }}">Sign In</a>
    @else
        Sign In
    @endif
</li>
```

Also it is unclear why you check `$showLink` that was set previoulsy.

Okay, as I've read your comments, I've modified template a bit with using `foreach` loop:

```
@php
// some initial variables
$allowed_to_click = true;
// this is a link to selected page
$selected_link = 'something';
@endphp
@foreach ($links as $link)
    @php
    // check if this link is ACTIVE
    $active = $link == $selected_link;
    // check if we can CLICK this link
    $allowed_to_click = $active || $allowed_to_click;
    @endphp

    <li class="{{ $active ? 'active':'' }}">
    @if ($allowed_to_click)
        <a href="{{ url_secure('some_url')}}">Some Caption</a>
    @else
        Some Caption
    @endif
    </li>

    @php
    // if link is ACTIVE - following links are unclickable
    if ($active) {
        $allowed_to_click = false;
    }
    @endphp
@endforeach
```

Comment: because it has ability to click on previous page (like a wizard pages)

Comment: For example links: Step 1 > Step 2> Step 3 -> Step 4.   If you on Step 4 page then you can click any links from from Step 1 to Step 3.

Comment: I understand, but why you check `$showLink` in a second `li`? How are first and second `li` connected?

Comment: If you on the second page (2nd `<li>`) it is not linkable but showing the text and class="active" only. The first `<li>` linkable but not active.

If you are the 3rd page, 3rd `<li>` is not linkable but active. All the previous links (first, second li's) is linkable

Comment: Also want to mention if you on 3rd page then forth page is not linkable but all the previous pages is linkable.